# Type hint equivalent of Dict[str, int] for custom classes with attributes of specific type?

Tags: python, type-hinting, python-typing, python-dataclasses

A user implements the following function, which is called from within my library.

```
def run(input_data: Dict[str, Union[Dict, Promise]]):
    pass
```

The library is in charge of collecting the required input data and the format of the input data is known. In this example input data could look like this:

```
input_data = {'config': {},          # type: Dict
              'value': 'any_value'}  # type: Any or Promise
```

The library uses the type hint information of the run function to determine whether the user expects a `Promise` object as value which enables lazy loading of the actual object, or whether the user expects the actual in-memory object of arbitrary type. Hence, based on the above type hint of `input_data` (it contains `Promise`) the library creates and inputs the `Promise` object instead of loading the actual object into memory and inputting it.
However, if the user would have written

```
def run(input_data: Dict[str, Union[Dict, AnyOtherType]]):
    pass
```

the actual object would be loaded into memory and forwarded to the `run` method.

Now, how can I achieve the same functionality when I define the structure of `input_data` as a `dataclass` instead of a `dict`. E.g. the dataclass would look like:

```
@dataclass
class Data:
    config: Dict
    value: Union[Any, Promise]
```

The `value` attribute is of any type but I have to know whether it is of type `Promise` or not based on the type hint of `input_data`. How could the run method with the `input_data` type hint look in this case, so that I can see if `input_data.value` is actually of type `Promise` or not?

Something like this does obviously not work:

```
def run(input_data: Data[value: Promise]):
    pass
```

And only writing

```
def run(input_data: Data):
    pass
```

does not tell me whether `input_data.value` is of type `Promise`.

Is there any way to add additional information to the custom `Data` type hint, that annotates that the value attribute for this Data instance is of type `Promise`?

Thanks for your insights :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you can get what you're looking for by inheriting from `typing.Generic`, like this:

```
from typing import Generic, TypeVar, Dict
from dataclasses import dataclass 
    
T = TypeVar('T')


@dataclass
class Data(Generic[T]):
    config: Dict 
    value: T
```

If you define your `Data` class like this, you'll be able to write type hints like `Data[int]` and `Data[Promise]`, and these will signify (respectively) "an instance of `Data` where the `value` attribute is of type `int`" and "an instance of `Data` where the `value` attribute is of type `Promise`"